# Windows Explorer IDs name

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I am wondering what the string at the end of

```
GodMode.{ED7BA470-8E54-465E-825C-99712043E01C}
```

is called (`{ED7BA470-8E54-465E-825C-99712043E01C}`). I want to call it some sort of uuid, but I am not sure. And how do I get these "uuids" from say a control panel screen or My Computer. I know the "uuid" for My Computer is `{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}` and the one for Libraries is `{450D8FBA-AD25-11D0-98A8-0800361B1103}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a ["CLSID"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID#Subtypes) – an UUID used by Windows to identify a specific "class" in the Windows component object model (COM).

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144096(v=vs.85).aspx
- https://code.google.com/p/libfwsi/wiki/ShellFolderIdentifiers